# iOS - Will Apple like Firebase?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-security

I created an iPhone app that is a guide for a local event.  The app also shows the schedule of the event.  I am using Firebase to retrieve the latest version of the schedule as text and display it in a table view.  I am done with the app! I will submit it to the App Store in a few days, but I wanted to know:

(1) if Apple will have any problems or reject my app because I am using Firebase?

(2) If there's any special code I should add to my app in the Firebase code to make it secure?

PS: I set my Firebase rules so that it's read only.  This is my first app and I would be really grateful to hear your answers

Best,
A

Comment: (1) Apple has no problem with Firebase whatsoever. (2) Security is a really broad topic, unsuitable for a Stack Overflow answer. Check Apple's video here: https://developer.apple.com/enterprise/

Comment: If you're set your Firebase database to be read-only, you know that nobody will be able to modify it (unless they have your Firebase secret or an admin token that was minted with that secret). Aside from that, it's hard to say what more you need.

Comment: aghanim, you could save moderator's time by clicking to delete the question, since it is not really an SO question.  BTW try "gamedev" for such questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using firebase is perfectly fine, just make sure that if your app needs a log in to have a test user for Appstore Review. And put the username and password in the box for test account when you submit. Put some demo data in it to let them know how the app feels to end users.